# How to aill cause it to ces when I try to d

Tags: c#

My program crashes when I try to do a decimal calculation starting with the decimal point. For example, ".9" will cause it to crash whereas "0.9" works fine.

Here's the code:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
            && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
            && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return))
        {
            textBox2.Text = Area1.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            textBox2.Text = " ";
        }
        else
            Diameter1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        Area1 = (Math.PI * Math.Pow((Diameter1 / 2), 2));
    }
```

Comment: Could you please post the calculation? Thanks

Comment: How can we possibly help you with what little info you've given us?

Comment: Sorry, I thought maybe there was a set answer that I simply didn't know and I thought my code wouldn't be useful. Thanks for responding so quickly though

Comment: Also what do you mean by "My program crashes"?  There are *so* many things that that could mean.

Comment: It stops and highlights this line of code:
Diameter1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text)

Apologies again! New to this.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: It says 'input string was not in correct format'

Answer (score 0):

As you are updating the value while you are typing, it will fail when you have typed the period and the textbox only contains `"."`. When you parse that, it will cause an exception.

Use `TryParse` to attempt to parse the value, and do something else if the parsing fails. Example:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox1.Text == String.Empty) {
    textBox2.Text = " ";
  } else {
    if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out Diameter1)) {
      Area1 = Math.PI * Math.Pow((Diameter1 / 2), 2);
      textBox2.Text = Area1.ToString();
    } else {
      textBox2.Text = "-not numeric-";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @BobWood: There is no problem parsing a string like `".9"`, the digit before the decimal separator is not mandatory. It's the step before that when you have only typed `"."` where it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're passing non-numeric text to a function that requires a numeric value:

```
Diameter1 = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

This could happen for instance if you changed your textbox value to "hello".   What you need to do is put another conditional statement in to make sure your code only accepts "numeric" text.

Bear with me I'm working on an example...